# Bound on a certain difference of expectations involving Lipschitz functions

Tags: probability, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds, lipschitz-functions, smooth-functions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with full support on the interval $[-1,1]$, with $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$. (You may assume the existence of a p.d.f. for $X$ if it helps.)

For any $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we define $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in[-1,1]}{|f(x)|}$.

I would like to prove that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all sufficiently small $\sigma\in(0,1]$, and for all $g,h:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, bounded and Lipschitz continuous,  with $g(0)=h(0)=0$ and with sufficiently small $\|g-h\|_{\infty}>0$:

$$|\mathbb{E}[g(\sigma X)-h(\sigma X)]|\le C \sigma \|g-h\|_{\infty}.$$

Without the $\sigma$ on the right hand side, this inequality would follow immediately from boundedness. Were the $\|g-h\|_{\infty}$ replaced with the Lipschitz constant of $g-h$ then this would follow from $g$ and $h$ being Lipschitz.

Is the claim above true as it stands? If not, are there non-trivial additional assumptions under which it holds? For example, it holds if $g$ and $h$ are quadratic functions (see below), which is suggestive of smoothness helping.

Additional conditions may be placed on $X$ or on the set from which $g$ and $h$ are taken. Conditions should not be placed directly on $g-h$.

---

**Proof in the quadratic case:**

Suppose $g(x)-h(x)=a x^2 + b x$, which holds if $g$ and $h$ are each quadratic. (The intercept must be $0$ as $g(0)-h(0)=0$.)

Then:
$$|\mathbb{E}[g(\sigma X)-h(\sigma X)]|=\sigma^2 |a| \mathbb{E}[X^2].$$

Note also that:
\begin{gather*}
\|g-h\|_\infty\ge \max{\{|g(1)-h(1)|,|g(-1)-h(-1)|\}}=\max{\{|a+b|,|a-b|\}}\\
=\max{\{a+b,-(a+b),a-b,-(a-b)\}}=|a|+|b|\ge |a|.
\end{gather*}

Thus as $\sigma\le 1$:
$$|\mathbb{E}[g(\sigma X)-h(\sigma X)]|\le \mathbb{E}[X^2] \sigma \|g-h\|_\infty,$$
as required (with $C=\mathbb{E}[X^2]$).

Note that we could have proven something even stronger, with $\sigma^2$ not $\sigma$. This makes me optimistic that this may hold more generally.

Comment: If $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $g-h$, then $\lVert g-h\rVert_\infty\le L$ and there are certainly some adversarial distributions for $X$ such that $\sigma L\lesssim |\mathsf{E} (g-h)(\sigma X)|$. So unless you are also asking for conditions on the distribution of $X$, it's all about comparing $\lVert g-h\rVert_\infty$ and $L$.

Comment: I'd be interested in conditions on X that would work too.

Comment: To be honest I don't know, such conditions on $X$ will probably be quite artificial. But I guess it's decent to look at conditions such as $\lVert (g-h)'\rVert_\infty\lesssim \lVert g-h\rVert_\infty$ -- since it covers your example of quadratic functions.

Comment: The condition on g must be independent of h and vice versa. They are both drawn from the same set.

Comment: @md5 I've clarified what type of conditions I can consider in the question (not directly on $g-h$!). I've also added a proof for the quadratic case which is hopefully suggestive.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\R{\mathbb{R}}\def\paren#1{\left(#1\right)}$The proposition is not true. It will be proved that there exists a random variable $X$ such that $X \in [-1, 1]$, $E(X) = 0$, and for any $C > 0$, $0 < σ < 1$, $ε > 0$, there exists $0 < σ_0 < σ$ and a Lipschitzian $f: [-1, 1] → \R$ such that $f(0) = 0$, $0 < \|f\|_∞ < ε$, but$$
|E(f(σ_0 X))| > Cσ_0 \|f\|_∞.
$$

Take $X \sim U(-1, 1)$. For any $C > 0$, $0 < σ < 1$, $ε > 0$, take$$
σ_0 = \min\paren{ \frac{1}{3C}, \frac{σ}{2} },\quad f(x) = \frac{ε}{2} \min(3C|x|, 1).
$$
Then $0 < σ_0 < σ$, $f(0) = 0$, $0 < \|f\|_∞ = \dfrac{ε}{2} < ε$, but$$
|E(f(σ_0 X))| = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{ε}{2} \min(3Cσ_0 |x|, 1) · \frac{1}{2} \,\d x = \frac{ε}{4} \int_{-1}^1 3Cσ_0 |x| \,\d x = \frac{3}{4} Cεσ_0 > Cσ_0 \|f\|_∞.
$$

**Remark:** Such estimates fail because $f$, though being Lipschitzian, can be arbitrarily steep near $0$. Thus in order to get a working estimate, the constant $C$ has to depend on $f$.

Comment: I take it that $f=g-h$. Worth noting perhaps.

Comment: So does this particular failure give you any intuition for what conditions might allow the proposition to go through?

Comment: So the quadratic case is the most general family for which my claim holds?

Comment: @cfp No, any family of functions with a common Lipschitz constant at $0$ will enable such an estimate.

Comment: Meaning? The local Lipschitz constant at 0 in the quadratic case is $b$, which is not common across the family.

Comment: @cfp But any family I mentioned above does have such an estimate. Regarding your examples, they work because the (global) linear term vanishes. So obviously a more general family of functions would be the sum of a function from the family I mentioned and a linear one.

Comment: So if we restricted $X$ to have zero odd moments, then it may (?) hold for a sum of a $0$-Lipschitz at $0$ function, and an odd polynomial? Any even polynomial is $0$-Lipschitz at $0$, so this class includes all polynomials? I actually tried to prove the polynomial case along these lines, but it did not quite work. It seems you need more than just the odd terms vanishing.

Comment: @cfp The subtleties here are what means “common” when specifying a common Lipschitz constant. Given the current wording of the proposition, such a family would be defined as$$\mathscr F=\{f:[-1,1]→\mathbb R\mid f(0)=0,\ f\ \text{is Lipschitzian},\ \|f(x)\|\leqslant c|x|\ (x\in(-δ,δ))\},$$where **both** $c$ and $δ$ does not depend on $f$. So this “common” also implies that the neighborhood related to the Lipschitz constant is common.

Comment: That again seems to rule out the quadratic case, in which there's no bound on the Lipschitz constant at 0.

Comment: @cfp I suspect that polynomials somehow controls their $∞$-norms, which is true for general functions.